# How to write the title of the step to be word on right and the other on the left

Tags: flutter, title, step, stepper

I want to write a title of the step in flutter to be on the right the date and the price on the left. how should i do this?

Comment: You can use Row(), then put your widgets in children[] and then align them using mainAxisAlignment to determine space between them. Check https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html

Comment: It's a title so the expected parameter is a string i can't add a widget row to title

Comment: got it. why not concatenate a new string ?

Comment: The concatenation brings the two strings next to each other. However, i want the first string to be in the right and the other text on the left.

Comment: add some fixed spaces between them

Comment: Why not using the normal title for date which will come on left as title (android) and using actions for you title. Actions will come on the right side of the appbar.?